# PHP: let a file return its own directory

Tags: php, function, store, directory

I am having trouble finding the rigth directory on my online server.
is there a function that returns the folder the file is stored in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP>=5.3 use `__DIR__` and before use `dirname(__FILE__)`

http://php.net/constants.predefined

http://php.net/dirname

Answer (score 2):

Use the magic constant `__DIR__`

You can read more about the magic constants here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: It's worth noting that this was only introduced in PHP 5.3 (as KingCrunch has specified).

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

> Returns the current working directory on success, or FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 1):

The `dirname()` function will return the directory portion of a path.  For example, `dirname('foo/bar/baz.php')` will return `foo/bar`.

This is often used in conjunction with the `__FILE__` magic constant for versions of PHP that do not support the `__DIR__` magic constant (versions 5.2.x and below):

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../classes/Class.php';
```

Comment: `dirname()` does not return an absolute path by itself. It just strips the basename from the given path and therefore will neither resolve anything, nor verify the existence. Use `realpath()` instead.