# php: get the directory in which resides a file

Tags: php, file, path, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: let a file return its own directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794362/php-let-a-file-return-its-own-directory)

Hi

I have a file located in a directory like this:

`C:\wamp\www\site\modules\file.php`

How can I get the current directory of file.php from within that script? This directory should look like `modules` in this case

I needs this directory name to build a URL path to a css file from the same directory.

Comment: hmm I tried `dirname(__FILE__)` but I get the full path to the file. I only need the parent directory...

Comment: `basename(dirname(__FILE__))` or `basename(__DIR__)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dirname(__FILE__) . "/" . basename(__DIR__)
```

or

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of pathinfo.

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('C:\wamp\www\site\modules\file.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
```

Comment: -1; assumes you know the path to the file when writing it, when the entire question is how to find the path.