# How to get just the name of the parent folder in the directory where a script is running in php?

Tags: php

I would like to get just the name of the parent folder of which a script is currently running in the directory?

if we have a script called foo.php with a path of "/Users/Somone/Sites/public/foo.php", how can i go about just getting "public"out of the that file path and not the entire directory tree?

any help would be great.

thanks.

Comment: I am unable to downvote, this has already been asked and there are tons of links to it if you do a google search.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882044/get-parent-directory-of-running-script]

Comment: I appreciate you calling me stupid. I was not able to find a solutions to this hence i posted here.

Comment: And i did come across the post you linked to before i posted and did not find it helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: get the directory in which resides a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804203/php-get-the-directory-in-which-resides-a-file) @rdlowrey There are dozen better duplicates, but by Aletheia, a duplicate it is. (Also keeping in mind that PHP version 5.3 just now surpassed [20% install base](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5/all), the 'most correct' solution shall be up for debate.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way to do it:

```
basename(__DIR__);
```

As @mario sagely noted, this is only possible with PHP 5.3+, so if you're stuck with 5.2 or less ... well ... you should switch to a new host and stop using legacy software.

Comment: Includes use the path to the include instead of the path of the file they're included in... any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
echo basename(__DIR__);
```

**Edit:**  It appears that `__DIR__` doesn't include the trailing directory separator, so the `substr()` call was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

`trim(strrchr(__DIR__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`

Answer (score 1):

```
    //on windows server
$cur_dir = explode('\\', getcwd());
$sector=$cur_dir[count($cur_dir)-2];
echo $sector;
   //on linux server
$cur_dir = explode('/', getcwd());
$sector=$cur_dir[count($cur_dir)-2];
echo $sector;
```

Change the parent directory how you need: -2,-3,-4

Comment: This was asked over 3 years ago, and the user has shown no effort to solve the issue, please, always be on the lookout on the date when the question was asked.

Comment: it's not important if the OP doesn't see or accept this answer, it's useful for future users  looking for similar solutions.

Comment: The most important on this solution is that it work with "include" function!

Answer (score 0):

if you pass in the script file (as the fill path to the file) as the arg for dirname(), it will return the parent directory.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

once you have that, pass that string into strrchr to get the string that comes directly after the last slash
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

```
strrchr(dirname(__FILE__, '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr(__DIR__, strrpos(__DIR__, '/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is with [realpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)
Returns the canonicalized absolute pathname on success. Very useful when used with  relative paths.

Say you are in your www dir

```
realpath('.'); //will return /var/www
```

then you enter the /admin dir but still want the www path

```
realpath('..'); //will return /var/www
```