# How to get the parent folder of current file

Tags: php

url 1 - `localhost/ocean/`
url 2 - `localhost/ocean/index.php`

```
$file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
echo $file;
```

In both cases result is `index.php` and that's ok.

Now, I need to get parent folder of current file.
So, in both cases result should be `ocean`.

Any help?

Comment: It is for `dirname`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: https://eval.in/669622

Comment: @Anant, In both cases I need the result `ocean`, not `localhost/ocean`.

Comment: Try this one `basename(__DIR__);`

Comment: @RamaLingam, result is `localhost` and `ocean`, I need `ocean` in both cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980244/how-to-get-just-the-name-of-the-parent-folder-in-the-directory-where-a-script-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `basename` DIR

```
$file = basename(__DIR__);
echo $file; //ocean
```

Comment: No, result is `localhost` and `ocean`, I need `ocean` in both cases.

Comment: Here I am execute the code and I get the result `ocean`. Try this one: `dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: Please up +1 If answer is useful.